# Autoencoder , steps_per_epoch,What value should it contain?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, autoencoder

I'm trying to create a stacked autoencoder with my own dataset ,evreything work great ,when i try to draw the curve with tensorboard i get this scalars:

[image]

i think the error is in steps_per_epoch if it's not X_train.shape[0] so what sould it contain:

```
autoencoder.fit_generator(generated_data.flow(X_train, X_train, batch_size=batch_size), steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0], epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_test, X_test), callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')])
```

and the other thing how can i add Accuarcy ?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are writing the summaries?

Comment: @gorjan thanks for reply ,i edited my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `fit_generator`

> steps_per_epoch: Integer. Total number of steps (batches of samples)
>   to yield from generator before declaring one epoch finished and
>   starting the next epoch. It should typically be equal to the number of
>   samples of your dataset divided by the batch size. Optional for
>   Sequence: if unspecified, will use the len(generator) as a number of
>   steps.

So you should set it roughly equal to `X_train.shape[0]/batch_size`

To monitor accuracy use

```
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mse', 'accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,that's what i was looking for.

Comment: for the graph The problem was in callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')] too i have two code that call the same log_dir